# Закрыть видео при закрытии модального окна

Tags: javascript, html, видео

На сайте есть картинка, на картинке иконка (play video). При нажатии на иконки появляется модального окно с видео. Код в целом работает, но не полностью). При повторном нажатии на иконку в модальном окне видео не появляется. (css - не показываю, там все просто).

Вопрос: Как подключить функции "append" или "appendTo", или другую функцию чтобы решить этот ребус?

```js
$('.video-icon').click(function() {
  $('.premium-design__exterior').addClass('open');
});

$('.popup-close').click(function() {
  $('.premium-design__exterior').removeClass('open');
  $('.premium-design__video-wrap').detach();
});
```

```html
<!-- Video-popup - Exterior -->
<div class="premium-design__exterior" style="display: none;">
  <div class="premium-design__video-wrap df">
    <video preload="auto" autoplay poster="./img/home/sec7_bg.jpg" controls>
    <source src="./video/exterior_design.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
  </div>
  <img class="popup-close" src="./img/cancel.png" alt="close-icon">
</div>
```

Comment: А зачем детачить видео, просто display=none  контейнера не достаточно?

Comment: Если без метода detach никак, то результат метода надо записать в переменную. К этой переменной можно применить метод appendTo. Для этого надо сохранять переменную в глобальной области, не очень.

Comment: Да, с глобальными переменными "не очень", конечно, но код работает теперь полностью. Так что спасибо Leonid.

Comment: Так зачем detach?

Comment: Видео можно на паузу, остановить, обнулить счётчик.

Comment: Leonid, а можно этот момент (паузу, остановить, обнулить счётчик.) показать в коде? Хотя бы один из вариантов. Буду очень признателен Вам!

Answer (score 1):

Возможно это и правильный ответ (у меня все ровно пропускало звук при закрытии), но у меня получилось немного иначе. Я присвоил новый id тегу video и прописал код к нему...

```js
$('.popup-close').click(function () {
    $('.premium-design__exterior').removeClass('open');
    document.getElementById('premium-design__video-ext').pause();
  });
```

Comment: Не важно как получать доступ к элементу video. Главное, пауза!

Comment: Согласен! В любом случаи - спасибо большое Вам, Leonid.

Comment: Вот, пришлось гадать что не так, для чего detach. Сразу же можно было признаться, что видео продолжает проигрываться или что там)